# Accessing "Review" table using facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How to fetch the review data(particularly ratings) of restaurants, movies, books from facebook using their api(graph or fql)?

Using the way as mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Review , it doesn't give ratings for many(none to whatever I sampled) restaurants even though you find them to be rated when you search for restaurants nearby in graph search bar.

Is it intentional by facebook?
Or if it is possible, kindly share it here with a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That document refers to a long-removed feature from the old App Directory which was [removed in 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/07/12/getting-your-apps-into-facebook-search-faster/)

(also: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/596/ )

There's no API to return content from the current reviews system