# Get reviews/ratings from Facebook pages without page access token

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs, meteor, review

I am trying to retrieve reviews from the Facebook page, but unable to get reviews as it required the access token.

Is there any way to get reviews from the Facebook page using page id without page access token?

I have found many questions asked earlier for the same thing but that still won't help me.

I also got the answer to getting reviews using places, can anyone know how to do that?

Or is there any paid service for this?

Checked following links but unable to achieve the correct result that I want:

- [Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages)
- [Get facebook public page rating and review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986885/get-facebook-public-page-rating-and-review)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get reviews from the Facebook page using page id without page access token?

No, there is not.

If you do not have admin access to the page, then you can not access the reviews via API.

> Or is there any paid service for this?

Any such service would be in violation of Facebook terms, if they acquired that data via scraping.

Comment: Thanks for replying, will you please let me know if there is any other way for getting reviews, I mean by using places or anything else that is providing reviews from business name?

Comment: Places are essentially pages. Admin access, or no access to reviews, that’s how it is.

Comment: As I am searching for the solution I have found some of the websites that can able to get reviews from the Facebook page without forcing the user to login with Facebook, that means they are not generating page access token, do you have any idea how that is possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unless they offer that for a limited set of pages - ones where the admin is also a user of their service, and therefor they _have_ access, I think that can only be scraping, which is not allowed.

Comment: @PiyushZalani Did you get the reviews of Facebook business? I have same problem to get the reviews.